# How many words are fixed by a permutation subgroup?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Let $A$ be an alphabet with $N$ letters, and consider the set $W$ of words of length $Q$ with letters drawn from $A$:

$$ W = \left\{ \mathbf{w} = (w_{1},w_{2},\dots,w_{Q}), w_{i} \in A \right\}.$$

Let $G$ be a subgroup of the permutation group $S_{Q}$. We define the action of $G$ on $W$ by

$$g \cdot (w_{1},w_{2},\dots,w_{Q}) = (w_{g^{-1}(1)},w_{g^{-1}(2)},\dots,w_{g^{-1}(Q)}),$$

where $G$ acts on $[Q] = \{1,2,\dots,Q\}$ as a permutation.

Let $W^{G}$ be the subset of $W$ consisting of words fixed by all elements of $G$:

$$W^{G} = \{ \mathbf{w} \in W \colon g \cdot \mathbf{w}  = \mathbf{w} \,\, \forall g \in G\}.$$

I am interested in the size of $W^{G}$. I have the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture:** $$ \left| W^{G} \right| = N^{\left| [Q] / G \right|},$$
> where $[Q] / G$ is the set of orbits of $G$ in its action on $[Q]$.

Is this true, and if so, how can we prove it? Something like this appears in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513993/how-many-lists-are-fixed-by-a-pair-of-permutations) question, but there no proof is given.

Comment: A string lies in $W^G$ if and only if it is constant on the orbits of $G$ on $Q$, and the result follows easily from that.

Comment: @Derek Yes, this was my intuition for the conjecture, I just wanted to make sure I hadn't overlooked something! But good to hear I was along the right lines, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As said elsewhere, its not a group action, see [$\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a subgroup of $S_5$ and the induced action on a vector space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321157/mathbbz-5-as-a-subgroup-of-s-5-and-the-induced-action-on-a-vector-space/4321161#4321161)

Hint: Since the group $G$ and the set $W$ the group operates on are finite,
you can apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem for verification of your conjecture.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the post to make it a valid group action. However, I don't understand how the orbit-stabilizer theorem helps here --- could you spell it out in a bit more detail? This is not a homework question, I'm just not a mathematician!